# Official designer designed a logo for my lab but it turns out that it's just a copy from somewhere else, should I report it to the university?

Tags: plagiarism

About 8 months ago, somebody in our university that works for our library designed a logo for my lab. A few weeks ago, when I was searching in Internet for something, I suddenly found out that this logo is just a copy from somewhere else exactly. I mean there is no apparent difference between the one that is given to me and the one that is already on the internet. I'm not sure if it is a violation of academic integrity or not cause it's not a research project, but individual that gave that logo to me claimed that she designed it herself. I don't want to put her in trouble for something that might not be that important and also I don't want to go to so many meetings with university administration people to describe what happened or whatever cause it takes time and just might accomplish nothing at the end. I appreciate any help or idea here.

**Update:**

One question is that does using this picture actually from this website needs some sort of attribution or it is copyrighted? I can't find any information on that. Indeed the logo is just that graphic at the top of this page: https://www.clicdata.com/blog/the-few-the-proud-11-key-principles-of-effective-data-visualization/

Even I can't find any information about when this page is posted online to find out if it was after that she designed that logo for me or it is just a really rare coincidence.

Comment: Can you just speak to that person (and probably her team and boss) before?

Comment: @user111388 Yes, I can send an email to her but I'm not sure if it's a good idea to talk to her boss.

Comment: Start with her. But talk to this designing organisation before you "report" it to some authority. (I mean talk to her boss only if it is one of her duties to design logos and not if she did it in her free time)

Comment: Was this logo already used in "important" documents?

Comment: @user111388 Not really. We just used it for some internal announcement in terms of emails sent to university students, staff, and faculties and unfortunately I used it to announce some workshops in my linkedin account. Other than that no it's not used in documents.

Comment: Is that her job? Or did you find a random person who had an interest in graphic design?

Comment: @AzorAhai--hehim It's her official job indeed that takes care of designing logos.

Comment: If it's a minimalistic logo I wouldn't be too surprised if it was entirely a coincident. I mean there's a reason why prior art patent searches and trademark battles exist. Can you refuse the logo?

Comment: If this is her job, I would talk to the boss if the talk with her was not successful.

Comment: @Cell I can put it this way that I won't use it anymore but I need some sort of explanation to my boss to tell her why I don't use it anymore or if I have a better alternative.

Comment: This is a workplace issue not an academia one. It sounds like the person is a staff member and not an academic researcher, so nothing about the way you should handle it is specific to academia - you should follow the norms for reporting dishonesty in any workplace. I suggest migrating the question to the workplace stack exchange.

Comment: @DanRomik Yes indeed the individual is a staff member and I'm OK with migrating.

Comment: @AloneProgrammer Oh cool that you have that

Comment: @DanRomik I'm not sure this would be on topic on Workplace, and I don't see it particularly off topic here. I'll first ask over there though.

Comment: In case you are talking about the "(|)" that is in fact a stylized "CD", and if the letters CD somehow represent your lab, I'd agree with *Cell* that similarity is not surprising - you even speak of near indistinguishability, but that *might* still just happen. It can nevertheless get problematic, in particular if there is thematic relation ("competition") with the other logo holder. -- Even without competition, a fruit plantation who used a stylized image of their product with part bitten off as logo once got sued by some computer manufacturer

Comment: @DanRomik As you can see from [this reply from a TWP mod](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/55650350#55650350), they wouldn't be particularly willing to accept this question, so I'll keep it here. I wouldn't consider it off-topic.

Comment: @Cell "Making up a reason," *i.e.* lying to one's boss is a very dangerous thing to do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I'm not sure if it is a violation of academic integrity or not cause it's not a research project

It is a violation of academic integrity.

> Even I can't find any information about when this page is posted online

The Internet Archive shows the image existed on that page 26 July 2018.  Furthermore, it's advertised for sale:
https://stock.adobe.com/au/189585864?as_campaign=TinEye&as_content=tineye_match&epi1=189585864&tduid=4956906e07434ca59f9d78b2979d22da&as_channel=affiliate&as_campclass=redirect&as_source=arvato

> should I report it to the university?

If you have used the logo, perhaps on a website, you should report this to university counsel.  They should figure out what to do to prevent litigation.

Of course it is possible the "graphic designer" purchased a license and then claimed the image was original work.  But it is more likely they did not purchase a license.

In a university context, you should have no tolerance for plagiarism by staff.